# How to take the value from array and put into session

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Here i have one array from this array i want to take fullname & email, and put in to session variable,i think to use foreach loop the we have to put session variable i tried but i am not able to ? can you please anyone update my answer

> print_r($user_data);

```
    Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [i_am] => Individual
    [fullName] => Kanniyappan
    [emailId] => kanniyappan@g2evolution.co.in
    [password] => welcome
    [mobileNo] => 9986128665
    [maxContactLeads] => 
    [otp] => 502649
    [otpstatus] => Active
    [createdOn] => 2017-10-14 20:24:18
    [regStatus] => Active
)
```

> I tried

```
 foreach ($user_data as $ukey => $uvalue) {
                    # code...
                    echo $uvalue['mobileNo'];
                }
```

Comment: To access `mobileNo` from `$user_data`, you don't need a `foreach`.  Just `echo $user_data['mobileNo'];`  Your foreach is trying to get `$user_data[1]['mobileNo']`, `$user_data['Individual']['mobileNo']` etc.

Comment: you know that you just could put the _whole_ array into a `$_SESSION['userData']=$user_data;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign array values to session variables like this:

```
$_SESSION['fullName'] = $user_data['fullName'];
$_SESSION['emailId'] = $user_data['emailId'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see what you are trying to do; When you run the `foreach` loop you are separating the `$key` and the `$value`; so you have to take a bit of different approach to your problem:

You could try simply assigning the `$_SESSION` values manually like follows:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $user_data['emailId'];
```

This will equal your $_SESSION to your `emailId` key's value.

You can also run a foreach loop and get the key's and values:

```
foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

This will set each array value to a session variable. And your output will create a $_SESSION value for each value in your array; you can skip some values in your loop by doing a `if` queries and `continue` on values you do not want.

For example, run something like this inside your foreach loop; this will skip the value where the `$key` equal `i_am`:

```
if ( $key == 'i_am' )
{
    continue;
}
```